# How to slideshow of ppt in iOS webView?

Tags: ios, webview

I am developing an iOS application to **slideshow and even manually move slides** of ppts(one slide at one time)upon a **webview**(in both portrait and landscape)using objective C.I have created buttons to move slides one by one forward and backward(one slide to appear at a time).Also,two separate buttons for autosliding and selecting animation types with which the slide show has to appear.I am using '**setContentOffset**' method to move slides from one to another.
**More importantly** I need only one slide to appear in webview at a time and hence i have set the webview's frame size approximately to the height of a slide by merely observing with respect to the view controller's size.

The **problem arising is in 'calculating the height of a single slide'** and **'the variation in the webview's frame in different iPhones and iPads'**.This slide height is further used to calculate the total number of slides in the ppt by dividing the content size of webview's scroll view by a slide's height.Since I am unable to calculate a slide's height exactly,I am ending with inaccuracy in moving slides one by one.Every time when 'setContentOffset' is called slide is moving by different amounts.

Please any one guide me in developing slideshow of ppt in webview with  exactly one slide appearing at a time and this application must be supported in both portrait and landscape modes and with all iPhones and iPads.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is the reference of the same for image view apply the same logic with slight modification in your case https://github.com/adamwulf/PowerPointToUIImage

hope this will help you !

Comment: Thanks Vivek.But in this method,webview points to nil once it completely gets loaded.This does not let to use webview further.

Comment: Does any 1 knows the reason for webview pointing to nil once the webviewDidFinishLoad method is called?

Comment: There was a mistake from from my side.I had explicitly referred webview to nil and had forgotten to comment it.This link was very helpful.Thanks.